# How to add paragraph to Bootstrap Modal body using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I would like to update Bootstrap Modal body with some data after button is clicked but I can't add anything to it.

I have tried to use `` $("#queueN").append(`<p class="boardNumber">Hi</p>`); `` and `$("#queueN").after("<p>Test</p>");` and `document.getElementById("queueN").innerHTML = "<p>some text</p>";` but none of these updated my modal. Does anyone know how to properly add

to modal body?

```
<div
      class="modal fade"
      id="modal"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="ModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
              Sėkmingai užsiregistravote!
            </h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="queueN"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a
              class="btn btn-dark"
              href="./puslapiai/svieslente.html"
              role="button"
              >Uždaryti</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
$("#register").click(function() {
      if (document.getElementById("odontologas").checked) {
        data.Odontologas.push({
          KlientoNr: clientId(),
          EilėsNr: queueN(data.Odontologas),
          Būsena: "Eilėje",
          AptarnavimoLaikas: "00:00"
        });
        console.log(data);
        $(window).load(function() {
          $("#modal").modal("show");
          $("#queueN").append(`<p class="boardNumber">Hi</p>`);
        });

        // $("#queueN").after("<p>Test</p>");
        // document.getElementById("queueN").innerHTML = "<p>some text</p>";
      }
```

Comment: Does `#queueN` exists at the line that add the data? `$('#queueN').length` return 1 ?

Comment: Get rid of `$(window).load()`. It is a deprecated method for one and is not needed inside the click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `$(window).load()`. It is a deprecated method for one and is not needed inside the click handler since the page will already have been loaded for the click listener to be applied.

In addition, the window load event only fires once in the page lifecycle and is different than using `$(document).ready()` which will fire any time it is called after the document is loaded